Is Cohort level hard capped?
A cohort's level is determined by your Leadership score. This score can go higher than 25 but you earn no benefit from doing it. Only an epic feat seems to break this rule.
When the cohort subject is brought in a conversation this point is never discussed.
Is it possible to go further without being Epic?
The trait Wicked Leader allow a character to get a cohort one level higher than generally allowed. (Your cohort must be 2 levels or lower than your character otherwise)
The prestige class Noble Scion allow your character to get a cohort one level higher than normal at level 2, as Wicked Leader and the same level as your character at level 10.
These 2 options specify a cohort can go to "Your character level -1". Does it mean your cohort can go further than the max level allowed by the leadership score of the Leadership feat? Or is it still stuck at 17th level?
The Noble Scion prestige class capstone would be greatly impacted. It is still strong but that would mean this capstone is viable for 2 levels and then become completely useless after that... Which seem... A bit odd.
Is there a rule that extend the leadership score beside an epic feat or does the Wicked Leader trait / Noble Scion prestige class override this limit?

This question is tagged [tag:pathfinder-1e], but then references Epic rules, which were never a part of Pathfinder (they are part of the D&D 3.5e-based d20 System that Pathfinder is based on, so Pathfinder easily could have included them, but didn’t—Paizo created their own Mythic rules instead, which work quite differently). Can you please clarify what you mean by Epic rules or “being Epic”? For that matter, the answer to “Is Cohort level hard capped?” is inevitably “Yes” since Pathfinder has no levels after 20th—I don’t know if the cap is 17th or if you can get higher, but it exists.

Oh yeah. Sorry for the confusion. I have read people talking about the epic leadership feat and could not find it... So that explains that part. They were talking about the 3.5 rules probably. (Might have been a really old thread and I did not notice)
The leadership feat gives a table where 17 seems to be the maximum but was printed in 2009 and so I thought it could have been some modifications or ruling somwhere that expand that.

I am going to vote to close this answer. all closing an answer does is preventing people from answering while the question is in this mixed-editions state. I suggest you take a look at Pathfinder's table and edit your question to fit Pathfinder rules making no mention of Epic rules. Then we will reopen the question.

It's highly probable that there's no hard-coded cap on cohort levels beyond the Leadership score limit. The game mechanics don't explicitly state a hard limit, and the Noble Scion capstone would be nonsensical if it was. The Leadership score is likely intended as a guideline for cohort level progression. It's a reasonable way to balance the power of cohorts, but not an absolute limit.
Prestige classes like Noble Scion are intended to provide powerful benefits, and overriding the Leadership score limit is likely part of their design.
How to Handle This in Play
The best approach is to discuss this with your Game Master. They can decide how to handle this specific interaction. If your GM is open to it, you could use the "rule of cool" and allow your cohort to progress beyond the Leadership score limit, especially if it's a core part of your character's story or concept.
You and your GM could establish a house rule that allows cohorts to progress beyond the Leadership score limit, perhaps with some additional restrictions or balancing factors.
